# Why are tags on profile pages sometimes 0 or negative?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

I was looking at a new user's profile page and saw this confusing area:

[image: 8 tags: 0 double, 0 long-integer, 0 int, 0 java, 0 var, -1 hide, -1 android, -1 soft-input-panel]

**What does this mean?** That the user asked 0 questions on half of them and -1 question on the others?

Comment: Have you tried hovering your mouse over one of those numbers?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, and nothing happens. Is there supposed to be a tooltip? The only change is that my cursor goes from `default` to `pointer`.

Comment: @Ben Hover over the *number*, not the tag.

Comment: There should be a tooltip, yes. Something may be wrong on your end.

Comment: So closing and reopening the tab made the tooltips decide they wanted to show... Before the only thing I could do is click them and get an empty search. Now, the ones with `-1` say `Gave 1 non-wiki answer with a total score of -1.` and the ones with `0` say `Asked 1 non-wiki question with a total score of -4. `???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number beside the tag shows the total score for the tag. So that means this user has answered  questions in 8 tags, 5 of which have a total score of 0 and 3 of which have a total score of -1. If you hover over the number in my profile (I show 2 tags with a score of 2), for example, it will show that I have 1 non-wiki answer in the tag with a score of 2.